# Possible to use Aptana standalone with vim with Mac?

Tags: vim, aptana, aptana3

I've just started doing Ruby on Rails development.

I'm trying to get the best of both worlds. I love getting around a file with just the keyboard like I can with vim. But opening up and find the files from the command line is a drag.

I'd love to be able to click a file open in Aptana and then be able to navigate around it with vim commands to do my actual editing.

I haven't been able to find any definitive solution for getting this working on a mac. I tried installing software for it with Aptana under Help >> Install new software as linked to from here: http://satyavvd.blogspot.com/2010/05/aptana-studio-with-vi-emulation.html but the link is 2 years old I couldn't figure out how to get it running.

Has anybody out there gotten this to work?

I'm using Aptana 3.2.2

Comment: Is opening up and finding files the most important issue for you? There are a couple of plugins and ways for you to easily open files such as with NerdTree and CtrlP in VIM.

Comment: Yes, finding and opening files easily is what I'm most interested in. I will check these out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know you can right click on a file and choose which editor to use, do you? Or assign any editor -- internal or external -- to any filetype in Aptana's preferences?

Aptana is based on Eclipse so all the Vi(m) plugins that work in one are probably going to work in the other.

Take a look at these five plugins:

- [Vrapper](http://vrapper.sourceforge.net/home/)

  A "regular" Eclipse editor with many Vi(m) key-bindings.
- [viPlugin](http://www.viplugin.com/viplugin/)

  Idem, payware.
- [Viable](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/viable-vim-eclipse)

  Idem, payware.
- [vimplugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vimplugin/)

  Run Vim inside of Eclipse/Aptana. I don't think that it works on a Mac.
- [eclim](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclim/)

  Eclipse and Vim talking through a server.

But if you only want a more convenient way to open files in Vim I can't recommand [CtrlP](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3736) enough. You could also try the similar but different [FuzzyFinder](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1984), [LustyExplorer](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1890) or [Command-T](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3025)) or you could get more familiar with Vim's `:e **/foo<Tab>`.

Comment: I ended going with viPlugin. Cost just under $20 after conversion to US dollars.

vimplugin did work but had issues. For example, holding down a dkey did not repeat.